# When I save the video in folder from gallery then select all video then current save video not display, but when I go back and return its display

Tags: android

When I save the video in the folder from the gallery then select this video not display. but I go back previous activity then display video

```
String[] vidfilePathColumn = {android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
try {
      videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(selectedImage, "r");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}

Cursor videocursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, vidfilePathColumn, null, null, null);
videocursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = videocursor.getColumnIndex(vidfilePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = videocursor.getString(columnIndex);
String vidstrlenght = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
File filevidpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(filevidpath.getAbsolutePath() + "/mantrademo/");
dir.mkdir();
File file = new File(dir, vidstrlenght);
getVideofile(file);
videocursor.close();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and make corrections in your code. `enter code here` is inserted between your code.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
immediately available to the user.

```
 MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
        }
    });
```

or

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File("your file path"))));
```